# Android Studio / IntelliJ - git-revert equivalent

Tags: git, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-studio-2.3, git-revert

I'm on Android Studio (latest stable) and I'm looking for some way to revert git commit using Android Studio gui. But I am unable to find such option. It seems to be missing?

I want to do exactly the same that I can do with console git-revert command: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert

Possible or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revert has been implemented in IntelliJ in [2017.2](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-57707), but seems has not yet made it to Android Studio